# BizTalk Custom Send Pipeline to insert a delimiter Pipe(|) at end of each record

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a receive schema, send schema and a map between these schema. I am using a Flat file assembler in the send pipeline to get the .txt file as output. I want the .txt output file with pipe (|) as a delimiter between each record in the send schema.

If the send schema is

```
<RECORD xmlns="http://BizTalk_Server_Project2.SendSchema">
<RECORDS xmlns="">
  <Name>ABCD</Name>
  <Age>20</Age>
  <Sex>M</Sex>
</RECORDS>
</RECORD>
```

If am using flat file assembler i get the output in .txt file as "ABCD20M"

But I need it "ABCD|20|M".

How can this be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used the Flat File Schema to the Send Schema and made the child delimiter as Pipe(|) (0x7C)